# PHP convert a string array list to Array

Tags: php, arrays

```
$str = 'answers[0] = "Love it"; answers[1] = "Hate it."; answers[2] = "Doesnt care"; answers[3] = "Like it";'
```

How can I convert it to an array?

Comment: First question is, how did you get such string?

Comment: Seems like a [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378). Where do you get this string?

Comment: It is not easy to convert it to an array...how can we split this type of strings...?? try to pass this input with just values only..

Comment: Agreed with other comments. This is a crazy format to be trying to import. If you can get the data in a more sensible format (eg JSON), it would be **much** easier to work with. Why is the data in this format in the first place? It looks like program code; what language is it written in? Why are you trying to import code from one language into another?

Comment: it's from javascript, there is a lot of data which store in javascript arrays. I tried to extract these data to store in mysql

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$str = 'answers[0] = "Love it"; answers[1] = "Hate it."; answers[2] = "Doesnt care"; answers[3] = "Like it";';

preg_match_all('/"(.*)";/U', $str, $matches);
$arr = $matches[1];

var_dump($arr);
```

Comment: Will work fir sample above, but fail if there are other string literals (or may be HEREDOCS e.t.c.)

Comment: Depends whether the OP has any other variants

Answer (score 1):

Use

> preg_split

to select just the values and put it in to an array

example:

```
$keywords = preg_split("/[\s,]+/", $str);
```

Just change the pattern!

check the documentation: http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-split.php

Answer (score 1):

```
$str = 'answers[0] = "Love it"; answers[1] = "Hate it."; answers[2] = "Doesnt care"; answers[3] = "Like it";';
$chunks = explode(';', $str);

for ($aa=0;$aa<count($chunks);$aa++)
{
    $chunks1 = explode('=', $chunks[$aa]);
    $myArray[]=$chunks1[1];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you can add new lines after the semicolons (`;`), take a look at the [`parse_ini_string()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-ini-string.php) function.

```
$str   = str_replace(';', "\n", $str); // <- add them in the source if you can
$array = parse_ini_string($str);
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```
<?php
$str = '$answers[0] = "Love it"; $answers[1] = "Hate it."; $answers[2] = "Doesnt care"; $answers[3] = "Like it";';
eval($str);
print_r($answers);

?>
```

Comment: Don't use `eval()` if you don't have to. And there is always another way to achieve what you want to. Also, there is no `$` signs in OP example string, so it's not an answer.

Comment: eval() is not a good practice..it allows permission to execute codes in the server for the input..that may harm your server.....so try another method ....

Answer (score 0):

```
$str = 'answers[0] = "Love it"; answers[1] = "Hate it."; answers[2] = "Doesnt care";   answers[3] = "Like it";';

preg_match_all('/"(.*?)"/', $str, $answers);

$answer = $answers[0];
print_r($answer);
```